# Rejection when changing array property in React

Tags: javascript

I receive an object from the api and I need to change the maximum quantity, I created a copy with let but the rejection still occurs as if I were using a const in this copy.

```
produtosComplementares = [
{
    "codigo":null,
    "codigoProduto":2,
    "descricao":'ADICIONAL PDV',
    "imagem":null,
    "nome":null,
    "quantidadeMaxima":1
},
{
    "codigo":null,
    "codigoProduto":941,
    "descricao":'ADICIONAL Retaguarda',
    "imagem":null,
    "nome":null,
    "quantidadeMaxima":0
}
];

let arrayTemporario: any = [...produtosComplementares];
arrayTemporario.map((item: any) => {
      if(item.codigoProduto == 2{
        item.quantidadeMaxima = 3
      }
});
```

the following rejection occurs:
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'quantidadeMaxima' of object '#'

Comment: produtosComplementares is array of objects, is not it?

Comment: Exactly, I have several objects in this produtosComplementares

Comment: Can you share the type definition of objects inside produtosComplementares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are mapping over the object you are getting each key value of the object
so if the item key is codigoProduto and it equals 2 you can not item can not also be the key quantidadeMaxima.

I think it would be very easy for you to debug this or just print item inside the map function.

Comment: got it, how can I apply this to change the "QuantidadeMaxima" when the product code is equal to 2?